# how do I RESOLVE ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python

Can someone run this and tell me where I'm wrong please and thank you! , input:

```
Enter miles: -500
Enter miles: 500
Enter gallons: 0
Enter gallons: 18
```

display:

```
Miles = 500.0
Gallons = 18.0
Miles Per Gallon = 27.78
```

code:

```
isErrorGallon = True
isErrorMile = True

while isErrorMile:
    try:
        miles = float(input("Please enter miles driven: "))
        if miles >= 0:
            isErrorMile = False
    except:
        isErrorMile = True

while isErrorGallon:
    try:
        gallons = float(input("Please enter gallons used: "))
        if gallons >= 0:
            isErrorGallon = False
    except:
        isErrorGallon = True
```

calculation:

```
MPG = miles / gallons
```

output:

```
print("Miles =", miles, "\nGallons =", gallons, "\nMiles Per Gallon=", MPG)
```

Comment: You are allowing Gallon to be equal to zero, thus allowing a divison by zero.

Comment: just use `if gallons > 0:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition on gallon is wrong: `gallon` should never equal 0.

I'll do something like:

```
if gallons > 0:
    isErrorGallon = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Be noticed, that the varible "Gallons" could be zero, and you are not excluding this.